# Meaning of the preposition "of" in following sentence

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in a english-korean dictionary, " How to make a friend of an enemy".

I'm confused why preposition 'of' is used in the sentence.

Does "How to make a friend of an enemy" mean " How to Turn an enemy into a friend " ?

What is the exact meaning of  the preposition "of" in the sentence?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. The sentence means, "How to make a friend [out of] an enemy." In the shorter version, "of" is quite confusing if you are not familiar with the idiom of "making a friend of an enemy." You are asking a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed,

> How to make a friend of an enemy

does mean "How to turn an enemy into a friend".  In this case, "of" is replacing the words "out of", so the phrase is the same as:

> How to make a friend ***out** of* an enemy